# How do you get gcloud access token in Python?

Tags: python, gcloud

I'm looking to do the equivalent of the following in Python with out having to call these command using something like `os.system` and look at the output.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/credentials.json"
export PROJECT_ID="my-project-name"
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

Can this be done with Google SDK?

Comment: it seems that for individual packages, like google.cloud.storage, you can create a client with explicit credentials, otherwise it will use your environment variables https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html  not sure if this is helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

Here the answer:

```py
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from os.path import expanduser
from os import getenv

# The the service account key ABSOLUTE path from env or current folder
service_account_key = getenv(
    'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS',
    f'{expanduser(".")}/service-account-key.json'
)

# Creates a credentials object from the service account file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    service_account_key, # key path
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'] # scopes
)

# Prepare an authentication request
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

# Request refresh tokens
credentials.refresh(auth_req)

# now we can print the access token
print(credentials.token)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this using the [Google Auth Library](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). You can install it with `pip`:

```
$ pip install google-auth
```

Here's an example code using buckets:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage


KEY='/path/to/key.json'
PROJECT='your_project_id'

# gcloud auth application-default print-access-token is no necessary
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY)


# Initialize the Cloud Storage client using the credentials
storage_client = storage.Client(PROJECT,credentials)

# List objects in a bucket
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs("a_bucket")

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

Good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```
import request
requests.get('http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token').json().get('access_token')
```