# Google cloud python API returns None for blob.owner attribute

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have created a Google bucket with "Fine-grained access control" and a few users have uploaded files to it.  Using the python API I can't seem to get any information on who uploaded each.  The blob.owner property just returns None:

```
sclient = storage.Client(project=GCLOUD_PROJECT)
bucket = storage.bucket.Bucket(client=sclient, name=GCLOUD_BUCKET)
blob = bucket.get_blob('foo.bar')
blob.reload()
print(blob.owner)
```

I'm calling reload() there because the documentation states it's required to pull some attributes from the server.  All other properties I try print fine (size, updated, etag, md5_hash, etc.).

How can I recover the uploader identification?

Comment: Getting the same result, looking like an issue to me. I would say open a new issue on [github](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I placed it here:  https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/136

Comment: I think I found where issue comes from, the [API get object method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get#parameters) doesn't return owner by default, it requires you to set`projection='full'`. Now I couldn't find how to set this parameter with `get_blob` method. [Description](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.get_blob) suggests that it takes optional `**kwargs`, but then it constructs Blob() class object which can't handle them it seems.  So it looks like the library doesn't support this parameter atm.

Comment: I would say make another request at Github to support this parameter with get_blob method. As a workaround you can get access_token with a [call to metadata server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59270269/12232507) and then use requests or other library to call API directly with needed parameters to get object and its metadata.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this, I created a ticket and it was fixed.

https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/136